# Couldn't view individual post that were in my website

Tags: posts

I had done my first post in wordpress but i couldn't view. It is shown in posts, but when I click the post title it shows [image: This is the screenshot of the error.]
What can I do to resolve it?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is this a fresh install? Have you set up pretty permalinks? Is /blog/ a category or a subfolder where WordPress is installed?

Comment: you can set the permalink. how to set permalink read this document. https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Permalinks_Screen

Comment: i've tried this. set the permalinks but the post doesnt show up. anyway will try it ones again. thanks.

Comment: Any update @Sarath?

Comment: yes the posts were in a multi site. so i had reinstalled wordpress as a single site and now everything works normal, thanks for asking, mate

Comment: Do you mind answering your own question with your approach, Post Your Answer, and mark it as such for the community to equally benefit?

Comment: sure, that's a great suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While installing wordpress, I had selected it as a multisite and due to this, the posted articles weren't shown in the individual post page. I tried reinstalling wordpress and now everything is working fine.